# Two exponents being algebraic

Tags: nt.number-theory, irrational-numbers

Schanuel conjecture implies this, so likely it is true.

Let $f(x),g(x)$ be polynomials with coefficient in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Assume that for some complex number $x_0$, both $\exp{f(x_0)}$ and 
$\exp{g(x_0)}$ are algebraic and $f(x_0) g(x_0) \ne 0$.

Must $\frac{f(x_0)}{g(x_0)}$ be rational?

There are no constraints on $x_0$.

Comment: Schanuel Conjecture?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Yes. And possibly others.

Comment: Wide open. You're asking, plain and simple, about the algebraic independence of the logarithms $\log{\alpha}$ and $\log{\beta}$ of two algebraic numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ having $\log{\alpha} / \log{\beta} \notin \mathbb{Q}$. Essentially nothing more is known on this question than Gel'fond-Schneider-Baker and its outgrowths, such as the Analytic Subgroup Theorem. Cf. Theorem 11.5 in Waldschmidt's book *Diophantine Approximation on Linear Algebraic Groups*, and contrast it (as Waldschmidt does) to Conjecture 1.15 on algebraic independence.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov Thank you. Do you happen to be Bulgarian? (I am).

Comment: @joro: I do! :) And you're welcome!

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov For the question, is it known that this won't be counterexample: take "conjugate" pairs f,g of the form $f(x)=f_1(x) + i f_2(x)$ and $g(x)=f_1(x) - i f_2(x)$. If everything is real, won't exp(f(x)) is algebraic imply exp(g(x)) is algebraic too? I tried this for a special case and ended with logarithmic inequalities without solutions. On the other hand in this case you can make f(x) algebraic for complex x trivially. Not sure if this makes sense..

Comment: Cf. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311726/special-case-of-schnauel-conjecture